# Doctrine, how to remove @Id from a field in a subclass?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have base class with @Id on some field, and it works ok for 95% of casses, but on a few classes, I need (for the sake of doctrine association) to map other fields as primary keys.

Since every entity should inherit from base class I'm wondering weather I can override mapping in some way, so that base class id field is no longer primary key on specific subclass.

`@AttributeOverride` do not allow for `@Id`, but also do not modify it if field already have it.

Any other ideas?

Specs:
Doctrine 2.6+
PHP 7.1+

Comment: "Since every entity should inherit from base class" urgh what? Stop using base classes. Use interfaces.

Comment: @emix Inteface + Trait for few mapped "common" fields? Make sense. Have to read code some more to decide if it will fix the issue.

Comment: Stop using traits either, be verbose. Some duplication is not a bad thing after all.

Comment: No. I need guarantee of availability of certain properties. "Copy paste" is no such guarantee.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense.